# PHP ignore $ character in string

Tags: php, escaping

I am using the following function:

```
function replace_password_line($data) {
    $password = "Ga$man";
    if (stristr($data, 'password_here')) {
     return str_replace('password_here', $password, $data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

My problem is the $ inside the string is being confused with a variable and the output results in "password_here" being replaced with "Ga"... the $ and everything after is being left off. Seems to be that it is being confused with a variable.

How do I fix this? Can I use a $ in a string?

Comment: Either `\$` or use single quotes instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to use single quotes. Double quotes allow variables to be included inside of the string, while single quotes do not.

```
$password = 'Ga$man';
```